Conflict between baseForegroundColor and tintColor in UIButton when changing image color
I'm developing an iOS app and facing an issue when using baseForegroundColor and tintColor together. It seems like there's a conflict between these two properties when I'm trying to change the button's image color. Here is the relevant part of my code:
// Reset the state of all buttons
optionButtons.forEach { button in
    var config = button.configuration
    config?.baseForegroundColor = .darkGray // Set default text color to dark gray
    config?.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
    
    let button = UIButton(configuration: config)
    button.isEnabled = false
    button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}

// Change the button state when pressed
if var selectedConfig = sender.configuration {
    selectedConfig.baseForegroundColor = .black
    selectedConfig.image = UIImage(systemName: "largecircle.fill.circle")
    sender.configuration = selectedConfig
    sender.tintColor = .red
}

The problem is that when I press the button, the image should turn red, but it only turns black. I tried to force the color with the following:
UIImage(systemName: "largecircle.fill.circle")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(.systemRed)

This works, but I don't understand why the color doesn't change as expected with just tintColor. Why do I need to use the rendering mode to force the color? Is there a better way to handle this?
I tried setting the tintColor to .red when the button is pressed, and I expected the button's image to change to red. However, it only turned black. After that, I tried using .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) with withTintColor(.systemRed) to force the image color to change, and it worked, but I expected the image to turn red without having to use this rendering mode.

You should probably be using the button's .configurationUpdateHandler -- but it's not clear what you're trying to do. Is this supposed to be a toggle / radio-button? Edit your question and post code for just a single button, and, explain what you want to have happen.
